# Website re-writes all URLs but after a while 404's them all

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-6, windows-server-2008-r2, application-pool

URLs on the website work fine, then after a few minutes they all return 404.

I've found some of the 404s in the log files, and they take this format:

```
2018-06-02 17:26:44 108.xx.xx.xx GET /store - 443 - 172.xx.xx.xx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 280
```

The 2 at the end appears to be a system error code: `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I cannot for the life of me work out what's causing this to happen.  The site works fine, then just stops and 404's everything.

Rebooting server temporarily fixes it, recycling app pool *sometimes* temporarily fixes it.

**Server**
Windows Server 2008 R2
Latest updates
Website target framework 4.5.2
IIS 6.1 Build 7601 SP1
IIS app-pool framework 4.0
Single application app-pool (not shared)

Comment: With this information’s only if someone have the same experience and solve it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by writing my own rewrite module.  Actual solution was a Windows update removing a needed registry key (thanks MSFT):
https://serverfault.com/questions/914753/iis-starts-serving-404s-works-for-a-while